# ¿Son las redes bayesianas un tipo de red Neuronal?

Tags: inteligencia-artificial, redes-neuronales

y gracias por su tiempo.
Quiero implementar una red bayesiana para inferencia probabilista de un proyecto personal,debido a que leí artículos que indican que una red bayesiana es mejor que una red neuronal para la inferencia estocástica, y fue ahí donde surgió mi duda pues pensaba que una red bayesiana solo era un tipo de red neuronal que tenia el teorema de bayes cono función de activación, pero parece que no es así, alguien podría ayudarme a confirmar esto, se los agradezco de antemano.

Comment: Hola, Jhony. Bienvenido a stackoverflow en español! Entiendo que su pregunta esta relacionada con inteligencia artificial y la ciencia de computación. Desafortunadamente, en este sitio, usualmente ayudamos resolver problemas especificas de programación (por ejemplo: la usa de bucle, o un error de bbdd). Esta pregunta se puede considerada es 'demasiada amplia'. Si enfrente problema específica en la implementación de la red Bayes / neuronal, puede incluirlo en la pregunta. Gracias.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, aunque tienen aspectos similares, una Red Bayesiana no es una red neuronal con bayes como función de activación. Aquí te dejo sus principales diferencias.

- La Red Bayesiana te permite saber el **grado de dependencia entre las variables**, mientras que una red neuronal es una "caja negra". Por lo que las Redes Bayesianas se pueden interpretar, mientras que las redes neuronales aunque hay técnicas que ayudan a su interpretación, es más difícil y no son del todo exactas
- La Red Bayesiana **los nodos representan variables**, mientras que en la red neuronal, una neurona por si misma no significa nada.
- La Red Bayesiana, funciona con el Teorema de Bayes, por lo que **asume que todas las variables son independientes entre si**. Esta asunción si no es cierta, puede hacer que nuestro modelo obtenga muy malos resultados, ya que en la mayoría de los casos las variables guardan cierto grado de dependencia unas con otras, lo sepamos nosotros o no.
- Por lo general las **Redes Neuronales son más potentes, y obtienes un mejor resultado** que con las Redes Bayesianas.

### En que casos usar las redes bayesianas:

1. En temas de inferencia y modelado, como tú comentas.
2. En NLP.
3. Cuando tienes que predecir datos con NaN dan muy buenos resultados.

### Por último te dejo dos imagenes

#### Red Bayesiana

[image: red bayesiana]

### Red neuronal

[image: red neuronal]